# How do I download and install packages without an internet connection?

Tags: drivers, package-management, internet-connection, offline

I need to install some packages to add a NIC driver to my kernel. Because I don't have it yet, it's not possible for me to do this from my system. What is the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/974/65926)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .deb files and install them manually, but without a connection you won't be automatically getting dependancies and updates.  That would be like going back to Linux pre-package manager days, about like... 20 years ago.  Perfectly possible, but much easier to get the computer connected and updated/installed.

You can also have a local repository that you take off-line when needed, for example [apt-mirror](http://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror).

Comment: I may not have explained myself clearly. . . I don't have an internet connection because my wireless and Ethernet are not recognized.  The whole object of this drill is to get the necessary drivers and do whatever may be necessary to make them work.  Any and all thoughts on this would be enormously appreciated for I have been dinking around with this way too long!

Comment: I found in my pile an old USB NIC.  I then did a new install of Ubuntu which recognized that NIC and I am up and running working toward getting the on-board NIC's done.  Thank to all for your help.